# R: Merging data frames based on file name

Tags: r, csv

My files (example as I have hundreds of these files):

```
France.csv
France_variables.csv
Germany.csv
Germany_variables.csv
Spain.csv
Spain_variables.csv
Portugal.csv
Portugal_variables.csv
```

I want to merge France with France_variables, Germany with Germany_variables etc. I know I can use rbind with the two files but I want to do this as a loop because I have lots of these to merge. I'm not sure how to do a string search and then rbind in a loop or if there is a better way of doing this.

I am new to R so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by `merge`?

Comment: add the data in France.csv to  France_variables.csv

Comment: Do you want different `df` from each country? or you want all to be merged into single df. Are the headers same or different?

Comment: A different df for each country

Comment: In terms of approach, I'd say the way to start is to figure out how to put each set into a list, e.g. list(France,csv, Germany, csv,...) and list(France_variables.csv, Germany_variables.csv,...). Then I'd use either a for loop or lapply() to merge them, where all the outputs would be in a list

Comment: I have made file lists as below:

    file.list.variable <- list.files(path = new_path, pattern = "_variables.csv", 
recursive = FALSE)
    file.list <- grep(list.files(path = new_path), pattern = '_variables.csv', inv=T, value=T)

but I am not sure how to put this into a loop to ensure France merges with France, Germany with Germany etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Get Unique countries
country <- unique(gsub('\\..*$|_.*', '', list.files(path = ".", pattern = "csv")))

#Loop
for (i in country) {
    dat <- list.files(path = ".", pattern = i) %>% map(read_csv) %>% reduce(rbind)
    assign( paste("df", i, sep = "_"), dat)
    rm(dat)
}
```

This will create dataframes like df_France, df_Germany , etc.

Comment: Thanks I'll try this

Answer (score 0):

Play with the 'grepl', and see if you can get this to work......

```
# set the working directory (where files are saved)
setwd("C:/your_path_here/")

file_names = list.files(getwd())
file_names = file_names[grepl(".TXT",file_names)]

# print file_names vector
file_names

# see the data structure
str(file)

# run read.csv on all values of file_names
files = lapply(file_names, read.csv, header=F, stringsAsFactors = F)
files = do.call(rbind,files)

# run only on WY.TXT and NM.TXT
str(files)


# set column names
names(files) = c("col1", "col2", "col3", "col4", "col5")
str(files)


# finally...
write.table(files, "C:/your_path/mydata.txt", sep="\t")
write.csv(files,"C:/your_path/mydata.csv")
```

http://www.rforexcelusers.com/combine-delimited-files-r/